# Перемещение по карте через balloon

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет.

Только начал изучать API карт, возник вопрос:

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было перемещаться по карте, при нажатии на балун(как скроллинг).

Пример: Если балун с HTML контентом на помещается на карту в мобильной версии, то мне нужно как-то скроллить карту влево-вправо, чтобы посмотреть полностью содержимое балуна. Либо как организовать скроллинг по балуну?

Answer (score 0):

В API Яндекс.Карт есть возможность [настроить модель интерактивности](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/interactivityModel.storage-docpage/) объектов.

Таким образом можно игнорировать наличие балуна для скролла добавлением к нему опции [interactivityModel](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.interactivityModel). Например так:

```
myMap.balloon.open([51.85, 38.37], "Содержимое балуна", {
        interactivityModel: 'default#silent'
});
```